# Assign Value In Base Controller From Post Request In ASP.Net core web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have many controllers which are dependent on one variable which is let's say projectId.

So on every request of all methods I have to parse projectId as below. so is it possible to get this value in base controller variable and use it directly for all methods. I found some actionexecuting and initialize way, but they were examples in .net, I could not manage to get in asp.net core web API.

```
public void Save([FromBody]JObject data)
        {
            new SaveMethod((int)data["projectId"])
                .Save((string)data["otherData"]);
        }
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using model binding to get a strongly-typed input parameter?

Comment: i have to create lot of models each method. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the default model binding , create a class and application will automatically bind to object after getting the post request :

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] MyValue value)
{
}

public class MyValue {
    public int projectID { get; set; }

    //Other property 
}
```

And the request will be something like :

```
POST https://localhost:XXXX/api/values
Content-Type: application/json

{"projectID": 1}
```

Then you can [save to session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for later access if you want the data available across requests.

Or you can just not use model binding(remove `[FromBody]` parameter , model binding execute before filter) , and get the request body in `OnActionExecuting` and save to session  for later access :

```
public class MyControllerBase: Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);


        var bodyStr = "";
        var req = context.HttpContext.Request;

        // Allows using several time the stream in ASP.Net Core
        req.EnableRewind();

        // Arguments: Stream, Encoding, detect encoding, buffer size 
        // AND, the most important: keep stream opened
        using (StreamReader reader
                = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
        {
            bodyStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Rewind, so the core is not lost when it looks the body for the request
        req.Body.Position = 0;

    }

}
```

And you can make your controller inherits `MyControllerBase` and modify that to meet your requirement .

Comment: I am using .net core web api. in this onactionexecuting is not working. it gives error as "no suitable method found to override".

Comment: using model binding, I will have to create lot of models. per method.

Comment: ok got it. I was inheriting controllerbase instead of controller. thats why onactionexecuting was not working.